# how to add last values of same group in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have a table like this

```
  attribute_id      product_id       quantity
       1              101               10
       2              101               7
       3              101               8
       4              102               2
       5              102               8
       6              102               6
       7              103               30
       8              103               25
       9              103               20
```

After the query, I want to find a query like this.
This is the semi-answer

```
    attribute_id  product_id   quantity
      3              101           8
      6              102           6
      9              103           20
```

The final output will be

[image: this]

Comment: Hint : `sum(quantity)`

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server

Comment: This is on MYSQL server

Comment: He tagged phpmyadmin, my guess is mysql...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Select sum(quantity) as quantity 
  from table 
where attribute_id in 
   (Select max(attribute_id) from 
     table 
     Group by product_id
   ) t
```

The inner query will give you attribute id 3,6,9 and you can do a sum of their quantity in outer query.

Comment: Doesn't need "t" at the end of query

Comment: In many databases you need a table alias. No harm is putting it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `top 1 with ties` with `row_number` to get the row for each product_id having max attribute_id and use `sum` on the found quantity values.

```
select sum(quantity) as quantity
from (
    select top 1
    with ties quantity
    from your_table
    order by row_number() over (
            partition by product_id order by attribute_id desc
            )
    ) t;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/SUSB44663)

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**: Use sub query and take the maximum `attribute_id` with `MAX` for each `product_id` and join as below:

```
select sum(quantity) from <table> t
inner join (select product_id, 
                max(attribute_id) as attribute_id 
            from <table> 
            group by product_id) t1 on t1.product_id = t.product_id
    and t1.attribute_id = t.attribute_id
```

Comment: hahahaha..... inner query will give 101,102,103.... it will definately sum all quantity

Comment: I think you have missed `attribute_id` which will returning maximum attribution as `3,6,9` and then join will perform exactly as expected. Please try it before leaving any comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
SUM(tnm.quantity) AS MaxQuantity
FROM(
select product_id , MAX(attribute_id) AS LastAttribute
from table_Name1
group by product_id
)lc inner join table_Name1 as tnm on tnm.attribute_id =  lc.LastAttribute 
AND tnm.product_id =  lc.product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
select sum(b.quantity)
from   table_Name1 
where  Attribute_id in 
       (Select max(Attribute_id)
        from  table_Name1 group by Product_Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;With cte(attribute_id,product_id,quantity)
AS
(
SELECT  1,101,10 UNION ALL
SELECT  2,101,7  UNION ALL
SELECT  3,101,8  UNION ALL
SELECT  4,102,2  UNION ALL
SELECT  5,102,8  UNION ALL
SELECT  6,102,6  UNION ALL
SELECT  7,103,30 UNION ALL
SELECT  8,103,25 UNION ALL
SELECT  9,103,20
)
SELECT SUM(quantity) As Sumquantity From
(
SELECT *,Row_number()OVER(Partition BY product_id order by attribute_id) AS Rno from cte
)dt where dt.Rno=3
```